# How to send request using customized Hooks in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I was trying to create a custom Hooks for handling input HTTP request from any component by simply calling the useHttpPOSTHandler and want to use  .then with Axios but its getting failed and error is
as  i  am new in react not able to debug this 
what i have tried

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useHttpPOSTHandler = ({url , data}) => {
    const [httpData, setHttpData] = useState();

    const apiMethod = useCallback( ({url , data}) => {
        axios
          .post(url , data)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.data)
            setHttpData(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }, [setHttpData])

    return [ httpData , apiMethod];
};

export default useHttpPOSTHandler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to useHTTPPostHandler are expected to be an object with keys url and data instead you are passing them individually causing a syntax error, wrap them within `{}`

```
const getData = useHttpPOSTHandler(
     { url: 'url', data: { "password": userPassword, "username": userName }
});
```

EDIT: As per your update, you won't see the updated data as soon as you make an API call. It will reflect in the next render

```
import useHttpPOSTHandler from "...."
const MyFunc = () => {
    const [httpData, apiMethod] = useHttpPOSTHandlerdotthen()

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        apiMethod({url: 'url' , data: { "password": userPassword, "username": userName }})
    }

   if(httpData){
       console.log("entered in api method")
       console.log(httpData)
   }

   return (
      <div>
         ...
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shubham Khatri  i just update the question is that logic right? i dont want to use useEfect

Comment: updated the answer,your logic is almost correct barring the fact that the data is available on next render

Comment: hi @Shubham Khatri can you tell how to route from one page to another in reactjs as i am beginner in it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431471/how-to-route-from-one-page-to-another-in-react-hooks